# How to get list of ongoing calls in Asterisk Java?

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-java

I was wondering, how can one get the list of ongoing calls in Asterisk when using Asterisk-Java?

It is needed when e.g. restarting ManagerAPI and I would like to display all the calls, which are currently running on Asterisk.

Previously it was done by observing properties on Channels created in Asterisk (I think it was 'linkedChannel' property), but this is now (Asterisk 13) not possible - linkedChannel is not updated when call is created.

Answer (score 0):

You should issue via AMI **COMMAND** action with "core show channels concise" and collect output.